# Trouble starting an algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm having trouble on thinking of away to attack this problem.

X is defined below. For n=1,x=0.5,n=2,x=0.833.As you add more terms, X increases. Calculate n for which X becomes larger than 4. First write the algorithm and then implement the code in C.

x= 1/2+1/3+...1/n+1  answer: n = 83

The only thing I'm sure of is that it uses a for loop.At first I was thinking something like

```
   For(int i = 0; i <= n.....
```

That doesn't seem close though.I dunno..Can I get a hint on where to start?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Try on your own. If you get stuck, ask for help. But we're not going to do this for you.

Comment: hints: "For n=1"  --> start condition.  " X becomes larger than 4" --> end condition.   "add more terms,"  --> step condition. ( increment `n`).  Body " x= something more than before"

Comment: Think about the relationship between i and n in this `x= 1/2+1/3+...1/n+1`

Comment: Your assignment is giving you any hint you may need: **First write the algorithm and then implement the code in C** so no need to flag any question with C before the algorithm is written.

Comment: Wasn't asking for the answer was looking for ideas on how to begin to tackle the problem. Now that I have some I'll figure it out. I was stuck because I couldn't see the problem now that I see on ways to attack the problem I'll do it on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will obviously compute the partial sums X.n and stop when X.n<4 and X.n+1>4.

To compute the partial sums, keep an accumulator variable and add the fractions one after the other

```
n= 0
S= 0
// Repeat the following instructions
    n+= 1
    S+= 1/(n+1) // Now, S = X.n
```

Remains to find the stopping condition. As the value of S goes increasing from 0, we will stop as soon as S exceeds 4. In other words, continue as long as S remains below 4.

```
n= 0
S= 0
while S < 4
    n+= 1
    S+= 1/(n+1) // Now, S = X.n
```

Translate that to C syntax.

Remains to look closer at the possibility that X.n = 4.